# Questions on a snippit of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

Ok, so I am using the [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) plugin. One of the examples given is to trigger the popup, trigger a spinner, do an ajax call, when the call returns replace the spinner with the results. Code is here

```
jQuery.facebox(function($) { 
 $.get('blah.html', function(data) { $.facebox(data) })
})
```

A few questions.

1. I thought that the `jQuery` and `$` variables were the same thing, and you use `jQuery` only when there are naming conflicts with other libraries. In this example, the author calls `jQuery.facebox` and passes in a function with `$` as a param. Am I misunderstand the difference between the two?
2. in the .get callback, we are calling `$.facebox` is `$` in that context the jquery global, or is it the variable passed in to the outer function?

Thanks for the clarification :-)

Comment: Please rename your question something more descriptive, like 'jQuery Facebox popup issue'

Comment: the questions I am asking are not specific to facebox, they are specific to the use of jquery in one of their examples

Comment: You're quite right. Sorry about that, on autopilot. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the author is sanitizing (freeing from any conflicts) `$` by passing it to itself--the first jQuery is to make sure it's jQuery doing it, and the jQuery object $ makes it okay to use. Just a precaution.